# usb encryption files possibly deleted, preventing the password working

Tags: usb, encryption, passwords

My friend has a Kingston DataTraveler Locker+ G3 usb drive. They are unable to authenticate with their password since they have deleted some files off their laptop.

They believe that they have deleted a vital file that is required for the usb encryption software to authenticate. The reason they believe this is that the usb drive password authentication worked prior to deleting a bunch of files, and also their colleague has had same problem and the IT department mentioned the deleting of an important file was the cause of the problem, they said a .bin file (possibly)

I am trying to find out how these Kingston DataTraveler Locker+ G3 usb drives work in regards to what files are written and where to. Is there a .bin file.

I'm hoping to recover any files needed to allow it to operate and allow the password to authenticate again.

Comment: Its an encrypted drive, you are out of luck hacking it.

Comment: Your friend if probably wrong to think encryption depends on files in the PC.  Kingston [documentation](https://www.kingston.com/us/usb-flash-drives/datatraveler-locker-plus-g3-encrypted-usb-flash-drive) explicitly says it doesn't. "*all the software and security needed is built in. It works on both Windows systems and Macs so users can access files from multiple systems, without installing a program on every computer used.*"  What happens if they try it on another computer?

Comment: Yes I am inclined to agree. If it required a file to reside on the laptop/pc then it would surely work on a different pc/laptop, as the required file would not be deleted from that other pc/laptop. I am trying to get to the bottom of why its not working so any input is useful. So thanks.